# Problems trying use Parcelable between activities

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable

I search everywhere, even in the android webpage, but I didn't found nothing. I'm trying to pass a Arraylist of a class: "ArrayList" from intent a to intent b, but always I have a problem, transfer the data but when the script try to transform from a intent to a parcelable or whatever, I only gets "**null**". I'm copying the code;

```
public class MedicalService  implements Parcelable{
    String MSrName;
    String MSrValue;
    String FnsValue;
    String Clinica;


    /*i deleted the getters and setters*/

    //------------------------PARCELABLE-----------------------
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeString(MSrName);
        dest.writeString(MSrValue);
        dest.writeString(FnsValue);
        dest.writeString(Clinica);
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MedicalService> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MedicalService>() {

        @Override
        public MedicalService createFromParcel(Parcel arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new MedicalService(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public MedicalService[] newArray(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new MedicalService[arg0];
        }

    };
    public MedicalService(Parcel in){
        this();
        MSrName = in.readString();
        MSrValue = in.readString();
        FnsValue = in.readString();
        Clinica = in.readString();
    }
    public MedicalService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

this is intent A

```
            MedicalService ms = new MedicalService(null);
            ArrayList<MedicalService>lMS = new ArrayList<MedicalService>();

            ms = xml_h.getMedicalService(session.getUsrMobileSessionCode(), idClinica , MSrCode);
            ms.setClinica(clinica);
            lMS.add(ms);


            Intent i = new Intent(User.this,Result.class);
            i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("MS_", lMS);
            startActivity(i);
```

and this is intent B (where i recieved the "extraput")

```
  ArrayList<MedicalService> lMS = new ArrayList<MedicalService>();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Parcelable[] ps = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("MS_");
```

I tried everything, a lots of ways to traspass the info, even with Serializable, but that doesn't allow me to put an arraylist. And when I'm creating the an instance of this class, appears an error telling me what my class need's to be initialized, but with a Parcel

```
   ms = new MedicalService(null);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 
lMS = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("MS_");
instead of
Parcelable[] ps = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("MS_"); ?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Shows this http://vvcap.net/db/v5q0UMmo6AAd-36ewbU7.htp

Comment: getParcelableArrayListExtra() not getParcelableArrayExtra()

Comment: ups, now show 'at com.offidesk.mobile.finmedmobile.MedicalService.<init>(MedicalService.java:74)' in logcat, it's because when i call in the method it inicialized null: ms = new MedicalService(null);. There's another way to initialize this Parcelable class?? i tried without the null, but happend the same error

Comment: You should use constructor without parameters to initialize MedicalService. Just do new MedicalService(). The constructor with Parcel parameter should be only used when reading from intent.

Comment: Awesome, man!!!, it was another new Medical Service(null) in the intent A who was messing around with the code. Thank you!